# Kotlin Coroutines: Hot Flow holds the thread

Tags: kotlin-coroutines

I am trying to emulate `BehaviourSubject` using `Flow`.

The code in the following sample does not operate correctly since the `collect {}` does not let the coroutine continue:

```kotlin
@FlowPreview
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
fun main() = runBlocking {
    val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO)
    val channel = MutableStateFlow(0)
    channel.value++
    val flow = channel.broadcastIn(scope).asFlow()
    channel.value++
    flow.collect { println("First: $it") } // Code will stop executing here ...

    flow.collect { println("Second: $it") } // Will not execute
    channel.value++  // Wil not execute

    return@runBlocking

}
```

Output:

```
First: 2
// process not exited
```

I don't think taking callback should hold the thread as well.
Where is the issue?

Such problem **does not happen with a Cold `Flow`**:

```kotlin
fun main() = runBlocking {
    val data = listOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5).asFlow()
    data.collect { println(it) }
    println("Done")
}
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
Done
```

Am I missing something?

> Kotlin: `1.4.10` 
> Coroutines: `1.3.9`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In both cases `Flow` is behaving the same, what you missed is that `Flow.collect` suspends until the flow completes.

In the case of the cold flow it clearly ends after the 5 values are emitted so it finishes execution. Meanwhile in the hot flow the completion of the flow depends on code that executes AFTER `collect` would return, a classic deadlock.

If you execute the `collect` asynchronously in a `launch` block it will behave the same in both cases. But since a `StateFlow` cannot 'end' by design it would end up waiting forever for a termination that cannot happen.

Comment: So is it even safe to use `StateFlow` since it just holds the thread? If I create 10 StateFlows, I'm actually wasting 10 coroutines? Am I even emulating the Rx Subject correctly? I doubt it.

Comment: It doesn't hold the thread, but since the main coroutine is waiting for the flow to end and the flow is waiting for a value from the main coroutine there is no work that can be done. Regarding `Subject` it cannot be directly implemented using a `StateFlow` both because it cannot be closed and because it has a few guarentees about skipping values.